# Is Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential cmdlet working?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get already created Password Credentials for Azure AD app using the Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential cmdlet.
The cmdlet is executing successfully, however the value field is empty :(
According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) it should return the key.

Did somebody managed to get this cmdlet working ?

Comment: I can't. Passwords are always hidden after creation. There is no way on the portal to retrieve the password

Comment: You mean you can see the password is existing in the portal?

Comment: The entry is visible with it's expiration date, but value field is hidden

Comment: well, I think I misunderstand your meaning at first. The `Value` should be empty, it is normal. There should be a mistake in the official doc, see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9hsq.png , in the example, it uses the `New`, not `Get`.If you try `New`, it appears like the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the `Value` should be empty, it is normal.  The `Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential` command essentially calls the azure ad  graph api `GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/applications/{application_oid}?api-version`. If you test with this api, you will get the same result.

There should be a mistake in the official doc,  in the example, it uses the `New`, not `Get`.If you try `New`, it appears like the doc.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me! I have updated the MS docs with this solution and awaiting merge