# how do I retrieve the password from the MicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential object

Tags: azure, powershell

I have to update a Script which should create an application in Azure and subsequently use it to traverse resources.
Among the commands to update is to create a credential for the application created.

```
$AppSPN = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "Move_Validation_SPN"
```

subsequently I need to use a credential to traverse the resources, according to the same Microsoft documentation, it can be created like this:

```
$creds = New-Object `
             -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential" `
             -Property @{ 'DisplayName' = $name; 'StartDateTime' = $startDate; 'EndDateTime' = $endDate }
    
    New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $AppSPN.appId -PasswordCredentials @creds
```

***Here comes the question***, when I create a Token, how do I retrieve the password from the MicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential object? which is: `$creds`

```
$Token = Get-Token -TenantId $TenantId  -SubscriptionID $SourceSub.Id -ApplicationID $AppSPN.appID -ApplicationKey $creds
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59042535/3245749) recommends using `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From version 6.6.0, there are breaking changes in this cmdlet `New-AzADAppCredential`**.

As mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-7.4.0), Az PowerShell cmdlets module moved from Azure AD Graph to Microsoft Graph. So, it is better to use the cmdlet of `New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`.

[image]

**Workaround**:
[image]

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788133), there should be a mistake in the official doc, in the example, it uses the `New`, not `Get`.If you try `New`, it appears like the doc.

Source: [New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0)